# PHP/MySQL - Error --> Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I have read many of the posts regarding this "Unknown column '' in 'field list'" error I am getting when I try to INSERT INTO my database.  All the posts I read, the error  includes the column name that seems to have the problem.  In my case it is just ''... nothing!

I hand code everything because I am not a "real" programmer and I use free stuff such as Notepad++.  I don't have any debugging tools.

Here is my code below.  I have many repetive lines so I cut some out.

```
<?php
//Connect to database
include("../ConfigFiles/ConnectDB_local_i.php");

//Populating the variables
$InvoiceNo = $_POST["nInvoiceNo"];
$InvoiceDate = $_POST["nDate"];
$ClientName = $_POST["nName"];
$ClientAddress = $_POST["nAddress"];
$ClientPhone = $_POST["nPhone"];
$ClientEmail = $_POST["nEmail"];
$STotalTaxable = $_POST["nSTotalTax"];
$TPS = $_POST["nTPS"];
$TVQ = $_POST["nTVQ"];
$STotalNonTaxable = $_POST["nSTotalNoTax"];
$TotalInvoice = $_POST["nTotalNet"];
$DescLine_1 = $_POST["nDescLine1"];
            ---I cut lines 2 though 14.  They are all the same ---
$DescLine_15 = $_POST["nDescLine15"];
$TotalLine_1 = $_POST["nTotalLine1"];
           ---I cut lines 2 though 14.  They are all the same ---
$TotalLine_15 = $_POST["nTotalLine15"];

//Writting to DB
echo "<br>I wrote to the database<br>";
$query = "INSERT INTO `invoicedata_table` 
            (`InvoiceNo`, 
            `InvoiceDate`, 
            `ClientName`, 
            `ClientAddress`,  
            `ClientPhone`,  
            `ClientEmail`,
            `STotalTaxable`,
            `TPS`,
            `TVQ`,
            `STotalNonTaxable`,
            `TotalInvoice`,
            `DescLine_1`,
           ---I cut lines 2 though 14.  They are all the same ---
            `DescLine_15`,
            `TotalLine_1`,
           ---I cut lines 2 though 14.  They are all the same ---
            `TotalLine_15`) 
        VALUES 
            ('$InvoiceNo',
            '$InvoiceDate',
            '$ClientName',
            '$ClientAddress',
            '$ClientPhone',
            '$ClientEmail',
            '$STotalTaxable',
            '$TPS',
            '$TVQ',
            '$STotalNonTaxable',
            '$TotalInvoice',
            `$DescLine_1`,
           ---I cut lines 2 though 14.  They are all the same ---
            `$DescLine_15`,
            `$TotalLine_1`,
           ---I cut lines 2 though 14.  They are all the same ---
            `$TotalLine_15`);";
$mysqli->query($query) or die($query.'<br />'.$mysqli->error);

//Close the DB connection
$mysqli->close();
```

?>

Comment: You are switching quotes half way through your `VALUES` list: it should be `'$DescLine_1'` (and probably all others after it), not the backticks that are around it now. Also: most debugging tools are free. And good.

Comment: You've got ` instead of ' for last 4 values

Comment: Wrikken, the backticks to single quotes was the issue.  Please submit your comment as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks.  And... off topic, what would you recommend for an easy debugger to deal with?

Comment: Okay Flyer, Wrikken did not answer yet.  You had the same answer.  Go ahead if you want the answer and I will accept the first one that comes through.

Comment: I was supposed to use the @ to make sure you get my comment.  @Wrikken

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same challenge for 2 days and the solution i have found is to change the COLLATION of my sql database. I was mixing latin general ci with utf8 general ci. I just changed everything in phpmyadmin to utf8 general ci and the problem was solved.